# Do security breach victims have any meaningful recourse?

Tags: pii

- OPM Breach
- Anthem Health Care
- Equifax

The list goes on...  If we define meaningful as non-monetary compensation (e.g.  services) to protect victims from further victimization stemming from loss of Personally Identifiable Information, what should victims be seek from these organizations?

Comment: Compensatory services are already on offer by [OPM](https://www.opm.gov/cybersecurity/), [Anthem](https://www.anthem.com/press/kentucky/anthem-offers-free-identity-theft-and-credit-protection/) and [Equifax](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/2018/01/equifaxs-free-credit-monitoring-time-ticking).  Are you asking whether those should be considered sufficient (which may be opinion-based)?  Asking what additional options victims might ask for?  Asking, generically, what these services are that they offer? ...

Comment: From a victim's standpoint, what is a thought process that would arrive at to decide remedies?